# Should I use workout supplements to decrease food amounts?

Tags: diet, strength-training, nutrition, food

**Some background:**

I have been working out in the gym for more than a year now after previous experience of 3 years during high-school. Also I have been running for 9 years, used to run half a marathon some 5 years back from now. I am 29, 1.83 meter (6 foot), 86 kg (200 pound), about 15 percent body fat.

I started with free weights in the 18+ rep range (due to an injury) and gradually moved to the 4-8 rep range, also I incorporate a lot of body-weight exercises.
Now I do strength training for 2-3 times a week for about 90 min (including warm-up and stretching), everything is in super-sets, and run 2-3 times a week for 30 min, mostly high intensity interval running.

My goal is strength, calisthenics skill, and overall fitness and health.

I do not take any supplements except from an sports drink (Isostar).

So far I improved strength and physique and mastered some difficult calisthenics exercises, added about 8 kg (~17 pounds) while remaining lean, and I am happy with my progress.

**The problem I am facing:**

I am consuming large and growing amounts of food. I am not stuffing myself forcefully, I actually have an insane appetite, and it takes a lot of food to satisfy it. I eat healthy whole foods most of the time.

This has literally became a time and energy consuming issue, I have to cook a lot, when I take food with me during the day it usually wont suffice and I buy some extra. And when I finally feel full I usually consumed so much that it makes me tired and heavy. Preparing and eating lots of small meals isn't an option due to time shortage. Also my metabolism send's me to the bathroom after each meal I consume, so you can understand why I am not excited about eating many small meals.

I am sure that this appetite is a result of training, because it usually lasts 3 days after the last workout. If I stop training, after about 5 days my appetite decreases and I eat half the food I usually do.

**The question:**

Will supplementing some of my food intake with a workout supplement allow me to decrease the amount of food I have to consume daily?

Would you advice to do so?

I would like to drink something that has high nutritional value and eat reasonable amounts of food.

Also, will I have to drink it for a few days after exercising, or just after my workout?

Comment: What does your typical diet consist of? Did you track your caloric intake for a few days?

Answer (score 1):

This question is more appropriate for [Health-stackexchange](https://health.stackexchange.com/).

However, I know that drinking your calories isn't ideal. Especially when you aren't controlling what goes into your meal supplement. That being said, anything that doesn't slow gastric emptying will not make you feel full. Starches and fat do this. It is the reason eating a bagel makes you feel hungry 15 minutes later while a bagel with Peanut Butter or Cream Cheese keeps you more full, longer.